# A simple function equals $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'd like to show that if $\mu(A_{k})=0$ then $h=\sum c_j*\chi_{A_{j}} =0$.

I can assume that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Because I can always make the sets disjoint.

What should be my first step?

Comment: Assume $c_j \neq 0$ for each $j$, can you show that $\mu(\{h\neq 0 \}) = 0$?

Comment: You're trying to show that $h$ equals $0$ *almost everywhere*, right?

Comment: I thought yes, but no I tried indirect proof for $A=\{x:h(x)>0\}$ and $A_{k}=\{x:h(x)>\frac{1}{k}\}$.

Yes. Almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue like this: $h$ is possibly nonzero on the union of the $A_k$, let $A=\cup_k A_K$. Hence if $B=\{x: h(x)\neq 0\}$, we have $B\subseteq A$. By the monotonicity of the measure, the fact above implies $\mu(B)\leq\mu(A)$. But by additivity of the measure (you only need finite additivity in this case) $\mu(A)=\sum_k \mu (A_k)$. Hence $\mu(B)=0$. This is exactly the definition of $h$ being zero almost everywhere.

Note: depending on how you define a simple function, you might include in the $A_k$ also the sets in which $c_j=0$. For the argument above to work, just notice that you can throw away these.